# How to visualize Loki JSON logs in Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, visualization, grafana, grafana-loki

So we are using Loki/Grafana to collect logs from our Kubernetes cluster, and the tool is great for that. But now that I have cleaned up the logs, I would also like to visualize them!

1. My logs
   [image]
2. Selecting only JSON lines

   ```
   # My query
   {namespace="default",pod=~"kkds-dockerscanner-test.+"} |= "SchemaVersion" | json
   ```

   ###### My logs

   [image]
3. I select only two columns that I want to display in a table

   ```
   {namespace="default",pod=~"kkds-dockerscanner-test.+"} |= "SchemaVersion" | json | line_format "{{.ArtifactName}} {{.Metadata_OS_Family}}"
   ```
4. Now I want to show the results in a table, but
   Grafana doesn't quite show the table I want. I want to show the output of my query in a table, and not just my output as a string in a column. Do you have any suggestions how to make this work, or can you point to a tutorial?

   [image]

Comment: Loki has no concept of JSON contained within a log message. For Loki, it is a string. Will have to think about it…

Comment: Ok, apparently, I missed the logQL part. As far as I can see from the docs, the return value for line expected is always supposed to be a single field. So we are down to taking the log line and using its fields as labels. Have an idea, but this will take some time.

Comment: In section 2 I have already broken the JSON down to line-by-line, so Grafana should eat the data :)

Comment: Well, yeah, theoretically we have identified the labels... So they SHOULD be available for column mapping... But it has been a while, and I'd need to do a test set to verify.

Comment: I have run into a few blog posts and videos where they show that you can set up Grafana with a REST API, and that the returned JSON data is easily digested. That is why it confuses me that the JSON in an identical format returned from a query cannot be digested. Here is the video, where Grafana digests JSON lines: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmgs1E9Ry-s

Comment: I know how it works in general. Simply adding a `|json` works for me for identifying the labels. However, as far as I understand you, you want (some) labels to be shown as columns, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by @Witt, it is possible to transform the JSON by applying a transformation.

If I choose the **Transform** pane and extract fields, I now get the JSON keys as columns in the Table view.

[image]

Under your datasource, you can also add the columns using **Derived Fields** and **Regex**. This, however, is a bit more cumbersome.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to apply a [transform](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transform-data/) on the data before it's visualized.

I don't have an instance available to me to test so I can't send screenshots, but this is how you'd get the data out of the "line {}" column.